# Finding $P(X \ge Y)$ when X and Y are independent and uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,...,N\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have to find $P(X \ge Y)$ when the random variables X and Y are independent and uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,...,N\}$.

I found $P(X=Y)=\frac{1}{N}$ since they are independent and $P(X=i)=P(Y=i)=\frac{1}{N}$, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to approach this problem.

I hope you will help hint me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$1=\Pr(X\geq Y)+\Pr(Y\geq X)-\Pr(X=Y)$$
and $$\Pr(X\geq Y)=\Pr(Y\geq X)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the set of independant elementary events

$$[1,n] \times [1,n]=\{(x,y) | 1 \leq x,y \leq n \},$$

each one with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$, that can be represented as a $n \times n$ checkerboard. The (non elementary) event $X \geq Y$ has a triangular shape on this checkerboard composed of $N$ elementary events (up to you for its computation as a function of $n$). The looked for probability is $N \times \frac{1}{n^2}.$